# Accented characters in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, powershell

I've just started learning Python(i'm using python 2.7) and I began with some simple prints. I tried to add accented characters and the file didn't compile at first. The I added: # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-     at the top line of my code. I currently looks like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# octothorpe character comments lines
    print "Hello World!"
    print "Hello Again"
    print "I like typing this."
    print "This is fun."
    print 'Yay! Printing.'
    print "I'd much rather you 'not'."
    print 'I "said" do not touch this.'
    print "olá"
```

I'm using SublimeText. Using Windows Powershell to run my code, I get this:

[image]

I can't see the character "á".
However if I use the terminal to code, like this:

[image]
Why does "á" appear correctly now and not before?

Comment: https://pythonclock.org/ && https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html

Comment: Cropped your pictures to whats important.#

Comment: you should use unicode for python 2.7.  `u"holá"`